# How to use withFormik with yup inside reactjs class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

My purpose is to create a register form which consist of two step. For the first step, user input their credential and then I want to async validate if username is already existed against backend. If everything is alright, then he/she can click next to continue to another step but all the data is not yet submit to server at this point. The second step, user need to fill some of there information and click submit in order to complete the registration and send data to server. To achieve this, i consider create two components. The first component is responsible for user credential and another component is responsible for user detail. After these two components are created, then i will create another class which will import these two components. The third class is created to make sure that all properties is safe if user click back from second step to the first step (I am not sure if this is the right way but it is what i can think of based on my current knowledge in programming language. Please suggest me if there is a better way.).

To valid client side, I choose to use withFormik and Yup. But, the problem is that, i could not make it work and valid my client side. It always throw me lot of error by return FormikApp in render method. I have tried return App but it doesn't work too.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link,
  Switch,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";
import {
  Row,
  InputGroup,
  Col,
  Navbar,
  Nav,
  NavDropdown,
  Form,
  FormControl,
  Button
} from "react-bootstrap";
import { Form as FormikForm, Field, withFormik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import axios from "axios";




class UserCredential extends React.Component {
    App = ({ values, errors, touched }) => (
        <FormikForm className="register-form  " action="">
          <h3 className="register-title">Register</h3>
          <Form.Group className="register-form-group">
            <Field
              name="username"
              type="text"
              placeholder="USERNAME"
              className="form-control rounded register-form-control" />
            {touched.username && errors.username && <p>{errors.username}</p>}
          </Form.Group>
        </FormikForm>
    );

    FormikApp = withFormik({
        mapPropsToValues({ username }) {
            return {
                username: username || ""
            };
        },
        validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
            username: Yup.string()
                .min(6)
                .max(32)
                .required()
                .test("username", "error message of username", async value => {
                    return true;
                })
        }),
        handleSubmit(values) {
            console.log(values);
        }
    })(App);


    render() {
        return (
            {this.FormikApp}
        )
    }
}
```